# Origin of "Dj" in words

Tags: pronunciation, origin-unknown

I've seen a couple of references to the combination of "Dj" as part of a word, normally in names, such as *Django* and *Ramin Djawadi*. Is the "Dj" always pronounced as a "J" and where is the origin from? Seeing that Ramin has Persian descent, I'm curious if this steams from areas around Iran?

Google was next to useless, as it like to reference disc jockey sites. :) Any information is appreciated.

**Update**

As Dan pointed out, once the origin is know, why did English select the digraph dj?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but since that phoneme originates primarily from non-English languages (*Django*: Romani, *Djawadi*: Persian), it might be a better fit for the more general site [Linguistics.se]. Though asking why English specifically selected the digraph *dj* for it might make it on-topic phonetic/orthographic quastion here too.

Comment: Scrabble finder helped me find: Hadj, Djins, Djinn, Djinns, Djinni, Djinny, and Djebel. These all look to stem from arabic-speaking countries. My guess is that is the origin. Perhaps there is a subtle sound difference that isn't a true "J" sound in the arabic language?

Comment: Yeah, that's how orthography for loanwords works. By approximation. And I think the majority (though I'm unsure and far from an expert) of the examples you just listed are Persian. As in Arabian Nights. But, as I said, if you want to know about the origins of the *phoneme* "dj" (see, I can't even do IPA), you should ask on Linguisitcs. They can give you an authoritative answer (whereas we can't, because AFAIK, it's *not* used indigenously in English). Similar situation to asking about the sound/surname "Ng".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs  to http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Josh61, Shouldn't the question be migrated instead of being closed then?

Comment: @VenomFangs Currently, EL&U can only migrate questions to ELL (and Meta). In fact, I'm not sure any site can yet migrate to Linguistics: are they out of beta yet? We can't migrate things to Writers yet either, more's the pity.

Comment: 'Dj' is also the romanization of Ђ in the Serbian-Cyrillic (pronounced as the <j> in juice) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dje  Not sure why wikipedia has the additional 'e' though, I've never seen that.

Comment: @Josh61 This question is entirely on-topic for ELU. The end result is the nature of the uncommon spelling _in English_. It might be informed by knowledge of other languages and their orthography, but the answer is specific to English.

Comment: @Mitch - as you can see from the answer it is a  question about specific linguistic issues. There is a dedicated site on SE ,I think it is  wise and useful to  informe users about it and recommend to ask there, not here.

Comment: @Josh61 Language specific orthography is entirely on-topic for the specific language. If the answer can also be informed by linguistic considerations, so much the better for here.

Comment: Several African place names have standard English spellings with a 'dj' consonant sound: Abidjan (the largest city in Ivory Coast) _N'Djamena_ (the capital of Chad) and Djibouti. In addition, Merriam-Webster lists _Djakarta_ and _Djawa_ as variant spellings for _Jakarta_ and _Java_, although I have never seen these used in English language books.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases, English didn't select the digraph "dj." The digraph is based on French orthography, like the spelling "Tchaikovsky."  Although this convention originates in a foreign language, it has become part of the conventions of English spelling, and not only in names such as "Django," but also in some words such as "djinn" (also spelled "jinn").

The English sound normally represented by the letter "j" (as in ***j**uice*) is called an "affricate," and can be analyzed as a combination of two parts, the "d" [d] sound of ***d**og* and the "zh" [ʒ] sound of *trea**s**ure.* Because it contains these two parts, the "j" affricate sound is transcribed as /d͡ʒ/ in the International Phonetic Alphabet. (The tie bar above the two letters is often omitted, so you might just see /dʒ/.)

Another affricate found in English is the "ch" sound of ***ch**ur**ch**.* The "ch" sound combines the "t" [t] sound of ***t**ime* and the "sh" [ʃ] sound of ***sh**ine,* so it is written as /t͡ʃ/.

#### French uses "dj" (and ("tch") to represent an affricate sound in words from non-French languages

It is thought that French "j" and "ch" used to be pronounced as affricates, just as in English, but over time the French pronunciations lost the initial "t" or "d" part, resulting in the Modern French spelling patterns "j" = /ʒ/ and "ch" = /ʃ/.

In the modern French spelling system, /dʒ/ and /tʃ/ are represented in writing by "dj" and "tch". (Spellings similar to these are in fact used in English also in certain contexts: "tch" and "dge" are used in English to represent the "ch" and "j" sounds at the end of monosyllabic words with short vowels.)

The reason why we use French-derived spellings for some words or names of Arabic/Persian origin is probably due to historical reasons; perhaps French speakers had earlier contact than English speakers with Middle Eastern and North African languages.

#### "dj" appears in a few words from Latin

There are a few English words where "dj" comes from Latin spelling, such as "adjective." It's pronounced /d͡ʒ/ in these words also.

#### In rare cases, "dj" might have a different pronunciation

The sequence of letters "dj" does not always correspond to /d͡ʒ/.

In some languages it might just represent a consonant cluster /dj/ (pronounced "dy," like d in *dog* followed by y in *you*). For example, I believe this is the usual German pronunciation of the name "Nadja" (a variant of "Nadia"), as in [Nadja Auermann](http://www.rightpronunciation.com/languages/german/nadja-auermann-9014.asp?id2=28&page=1).

In compound words, the letter sequence "dj" might simply represent a sequence of /d/ followed by the "j" affricate sound /d͡ʒ/. One possible example might be "[bedjacket](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bedjacket)".

Comment: Excellent answer. A minor addition to your third paragraph. French itself _currently_ doesn't have within its own phonological inventory the affricate and so it is natural for the French orthography to prepend with a 'd' in order to elicit an affricate. That is the explanation for the _French_ orthography. Why English does the same instead of using its own plain 'j' for an affricate, it is simply a borrowing.

Comment: @Mitch: Well, /dʒ/ and /tch/ do currently occur in modern French, although they're rare and mostly occur in loanwords and onomatopoeia. It may make more sense to analyze them as consonant clusters in French, just for reasons of simplicity. If that's what you're saying, I may edit this sentence to be ambiguous about whether these sounds are phonological affricates in French.